# Elasticsearch : Number of search operation per second

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to get the number of search operation per a second on a node (and / or on all nodes).

Is there a way to get this information **without the Marvel plugin**?
My ElasticSearch version is **0.90.11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marvel does it by sampling.  If you write a script to repeatedly run `curl http://localhost:9200/_stats/search` and parse the a result that looks like this:

```
...
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "search" : {
        "open_contexts" : 0,
        "query_total" : 51556,
        "query_time_in_millis" : 2339958,
        "query_current" : 0,
        "fetch_total" : 8276,
        "fetch_time_in_millis" : 34916,
        "fetch_current" : 0
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "search" : {
        "open_contexts" : 0,
        "query_total" : 73703,
        "query_time_in_millis" : 2773745,
        "query_current" : 0,
        "fetch_total" : 10428,
        "fetch_time_in_millis" : 45570,
        "fetch_current" : 0
      }
    }
  },
...
```

You can see the query_total values -- just repeatedly query those at some interval and then do the math.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alcanzar.
Here is the script I created :

```
if [[ $1 == "" ]]
then
        echo "Usage : $0 <refresh_interval_in second>"
        echo "Example : ./$0 10"
        exit 1
fi

refresh_interval=$1

while true; do
begin=$(curl --silent http://localhost:9200/_stats/search?pretty | grep '"query_total" :' | sed -n 2p | sed 's/,$//' | awk '{print $3}')
sleep $refresh_interval
end=$(curl --silent http://localhost:9200/_stats/search?pretty | grep '"query_total" :' | sed -n 2p | sed 's/,$//' | awk '{print $3}')
total=$(echo $(((( $end - $begin )) / $refresh_interval)))
echo $(date +"[%T] ")"Search ops/sec : "$total
done
```

For instance, refreshing every 10 seconds, execute : **sh script.sh 10**

Comment: throwing this error :  line 14: ((  -  )) / 10: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")) / 10")